# sql-server optimize query with lots of null checks

Tags: sql-server, null, optimization, query-performance

I have a query such as:

```
select something
from somewhere
join stuff on condition
join more_stuff on condition
where somewhere.sometime is null
and somewhere.someone is null
and stuff.whatever is null
```

and so on.

I try nonclustered group indexing `somewhere.sometime` and `somewhere.someone`, the query slows down. I read somewhere that MSSQL keeps a bitmap of nulls for each row.

The question is, how to speed up the query so that access to rows with the specified `null` values is faster and indexed? (so you only scan rows with the specified `nulls`, not full table scan) Can I somehow take advantage of this `null` bitmap ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NULL bitmap is indeed used for query optimization that involve columns with NULL values, but there are a few considerations here:

- NULL bitmap is not present on nonclustered indexes (you'll see why), on the other hand it is *always* present on the leaves of clustered indexes, and heap tables.
- NULL bitmap cannot be built for index records, but exclusively for data records (this is why you cannot have it for nonclustered indexes). That means you can have a NULL bitmap either on the table (organized as heap) or on a clustered index (leaves).
- NULL bitmap is not present for tables with only SPARSE columns.

You should check if you have a NULL bitmap indeed. My guess is that yours is missing. You could use DBCC to check the record attributes:

Open a query window and issue:

```
DBCC IND (DATABASE_NAME, 'TABLE_NAME', -1)
DBCC TRACEON (3604)
DBCC PAGE (DATABASE_NAME, PageFID, PagePID, 3)
DBCC TRACEOFF (3604)
```

where PageFID and PagePID are displayed by the first command `DBCC IND` then check for the `Record Attributes` and check if `NULL_BITMAP` is present.

If there isn't any, then create a clustered index on the table, and check again.
You could also give us the execution plan, and the actual definition of the table (with dummy column names if confidential).

Comment: Yes, it seems I don't have the null bitmap data. This was way too much information :-)

Comment: No problem, maybe it will come in handy for somebody else :)